# Select multiple choice flutter

Tags: flutter

What is this and how can I build this in flutter? I don't know how to create it and I can't design these buttons.

This is the design which I want to create

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you do not know how to create those buttons, this is a scuffed code but it should give you an idea of how to create it.

```
            Container(
              width: 220.0,
              height: 65.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [Colors.white, Color.fromARGB(255, 177, 177, 177)]),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
              ),

              alignment: Alignment.center, // where to position the child
              child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 2, sigmaY: 2),
                child: Container(
                  width: 200.0,
                  height: 50.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 226, 219, 219)),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                          flex: 2,
                          child: Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 7, horizontal: 10),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 78, 151, 185)),
                          )),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 5,
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 7),
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(child: Text("title")),
                              Expanded(child: Text("subtitle"))
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

should result in something like this
[image: Like this]

adjust colors/dimensions/radius and text accordingly. You can turn it into a button with a gestureDetector Wrap it with a statefulWidget and assign a pressed parameter to it to control how it behaves when clicked and what to change. Please be mindful of the dimensions when creating it, use media sized query to not over flow

Comment: let me tell you that these are multiple choice chips..

Comment: You can create a Wrap widget with the container that I wrote above as children, create a call back function that changes selection index on tap with a gesture detector, pass the selected parameter to each child depending on the parent selection index which should give you a multiple-choice behavior

Comment: I've mad this but couldn't fit it in `GridView.count()`. can you help?